# Is there any method to estimate the entropy generation inside the metal wall connecting two heat reservoirs?

Tags: thermodynamics, entropy

[image]

Hi everyone!
I have to split the entropy generation of this system into the species according to the individual component. As far as I know, the entropy generation can only obtain for a whole system but not for separated elements. I got stuck here and cannot go further in my research.
So, is there any method to estimate the amount of entropy generation in a single component? Can anyone help me to solve this issue?
Many thanks for your help!

Comment: hint: the entropy generated when heat $q$ flows through a temperature drop is $q(1/T_{low}-1/T_{high})$

Comment: If the two reservoirs are ideal, then there is no entropy generation within either of them during the transfer of heat through the conductive wall.  All the entropy generation takes place within the wall, as a result of the finite temperature gradient.  So the entropy generated within the wall is just equal to the overall entropy generated in this isolated system.

Comment: Assuming a constant temperature gradient in the metal wall you may use the formula in this [post](https://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/413794/why-is-entropy-generation-zero-at-infinitesimal-temperature-gradient/414120#414120).

Comment: Thank you @hyportex! Can you explain some deeper? It's too short to understand.

Comment: Thank you @Chester Miller! In my situation, the reservoirs are not ideal and the Temperature, heat fluxes are changed on time. The pressure in the reservoir 2 is also depended on time.

Answer (score 0):

[image]

Dear @Chester Miller!

I separated the system into 4 individual elements as in the attached figure, and then apply the theorem dSgen/dt = dS/dt - sum[q(1/Tlow - 1/Thigh)] for each element to obtain the Entropy generation inside it. Is it right? Could you give me some suggestions?

Thanks for your help!